# I have to run "npm run-script build" every time after I am changing my code to view effect

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs project having Expressjs and Reactjs. I change my code and reload, or `npm start`, yet this does not load the changes I made. To view my changes, I must run `npm run-script build` every time. How can I run this after any code changes?

Here is my part of `pacakge.json` file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/start",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "dev-client": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --port 3002 --content-base public/",
    "fullStart": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack && node ./bin/start",
    "debug": "node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION ./bin/start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Comment: Please mention the following script which located in package.json file => scripts => build, to suggest a proper solution

Comment: Edited @YasserMas . Please check now

Comment: Just run `npm run dev-client` it will watch all changes

Comment: AFAIK, *building* a project should only happen once before deployment to a staging/production server. Locally you shouldn't need to build the project as it would be too time consuming to build a project every time you do a change.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to deal with this problem is :

Install nodemon package using :

`npm install nodemon --save-dev`

In your `package.json` use this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/server.js" // your application start file
}
```

And it will load your new changes whenever you save the project.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular ways to configure your application to automatically refresh/reload upon file changes is by using [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload).

**Run the following commands in order to install and enable [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload):**

1. Install [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) globally

   `npm install -g livereload`
2. Enable [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) (first replace [path] with the directory path of your source code)

   `livereload [path]`

If the project was initially created via a popular generator (example [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) there is a good chance this functionality is already available. Refer to the generator documentation to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

i just had an issue with this and was trying to start up my application with `npm start` instead of `npm run dev`. In my case i was not using nodemon BUT i think that may help in some situations if you already have a package installed like nodemon.

in my case it was a clone from a stripe.js repo. which used next for similar nodemon type functionality.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run build' ./demo-react-stripe-js-master"
  },
```

when i was trying it with npm start i had to keep refreshing the page over and over every time to see changes. after using `npm run dev` it seemed to perform with the appropriate hot reload.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers